# How to split vertices into two paths with restriction on which two vertices can be adjancent

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem where I have queue of N people and M pairs of people who can't stand each other. I need to split these people into two groups such that people who can't stand each other are not adjacent in one queue and to minimize the difference between the length of these two queues. All the approaches I've tried so far are either not working or extremely slow and I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Can you share YOUR implementation/efforts towards the problem.

Comment: Also, provide some input and output test cases to help us understand the problem better. You can also consider adding the appropriate language tag like c++ or java or python

Comment: It seems more of graph bi-coloring problem. You can use [dfs like used in this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-graph-is-bipartite-using-dfs/) to solve this problem. The constraint `"minimize the difference between the length of these two queues"` can be solved by applying greedy choice over disjoint sub-graphs.

Comment: Btw, it is always helpful if you can share your basic idea about the problem along with some sample input/outputs.